# What does $resources mean while identifying the element

Tags: rspec, watir, watir-webdriver

I have come across these line of code while identifying the element using watir

```
{ browser.link(:text,$resources['Edit']) }
```

so what is the use of these "$resources"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dollar sign means that `$resources` is a global variable.

Given that the code does `$resources['Edit']`, it might be a hash that is returning the locator value. For example, it might be returning "text of element".

The `$resources` is likely defined somewhere in your code, maybe the spec_helper.rb. I do not believe it is used normally by rspec or watir, so it is likely defined some where in your specs.

Comment: oh yes $resources stand for global variable but it is not defined in spec_helper.rb file, instead of just mentioning the attribute value as EDIT why did he mentioned in that way..........

Comment: $ resources likely holds many values. Using something lile a hash helps keep the code nicer. You should search your code to find where it is defined. It will probably make it more clear why.

Comment: yaa i have searched it in spec_helper.rb and also the file in which it is defined

Comment: Well it is a global variable, so it could be defined anywhere in your project. Are you using some sort of IDE? Usually they have some sort of function for searching usages.

Comment: yaa i use eclipse IDE